# Could someone tell me any different way to make this code faster?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, min

The code runs correctly and it does what it is supposed to do, but I was told I could make it faster by using Boolean expressions instead but would not really know where to insert them here. The problem is:

> Given a sequence of n points with their coordinates, write a program remote, which calculates the value of the smallest remoteness of a point, which is outside the square. A point is outside the square, if it is neither inner to the square, nor belongs to square contour. If there are no points outside the square, your program has to output 0.
>
> Constraints:
>   1 ≤ n ≤ 10000 and 1 ≤ a ≤ 1000 ;
>   Example:
>
> Input: 
>   5 4
>   1 2
>   4 6
>   -3 2
>   -2 2
>   4 -1
>   Output: 5

Could someone suggest me any technique to make the code more efficient?

```
int remote(int x, int y) {
    int z = abs(x) + abs(y);
    return z;
}   

int main() {

    int n, a;
    int x;
    int y;

    cin >> n >> a;

    int z=20001;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cin >> x >> y;
        if (x > a / 2 || y > a / 2) {
            if (z > remote(x, y)) {
                z = remote(x, y);
            }               
        }
    }    
    cout << z <<endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Additional info: In the plane, a square with side length a and a center at the origin of the coordinate system is given. Sides are parallel to coordinate's axis. We call "remoteness" of a given point, the sum of the absolute values of point's coordinates. For example, the remoteness of the point with coordinates (2, -3) is 5.

Comment: Your code looks like it is trying to find the largest remoteness where your requirements say to find the smallest.

Comment: For improvement of **working code** ask at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) please.

Comment: signomi, am still now to the site :)

Comment: Everyone started somehow. I recommend those who blame 23ElCaliente for this question (down votes) to look at their older questions. He has shown effort and asks for help. To  πάντα ῥεῖ: there are many and many discussions on stack exchange now. But stackoverflow remains main programming related discussion for many of people.

Comment: Your code calculates some results repeatedly from the same inputs.   Work out ways to only do such calculations once (e.g. hoist calculation of `a/2` out of loop, rather than calculating it every loop iteration).   When changing a variable, don't use operators that introduce temporaries (like `i++`) unless your program needs to use both the old value and the new one (which is not the case here).    Try to avoid comparisons that are described using the word "or"  (for example, `a <= b` is described as "`a` is less than OR equal to `b`").  These are microoptimisations though - not much benefit.

Comment: compile with -O3! How fast do you want to have it? I think the bottle neck is reading/parsing the data, everything else will be optimized by the compiler.

Comment: Don't bother optimizing.  Your bottleneck is in the input section.  If your program takes 1 millisecond to input the two numbers, any optimization change to other parts in your program must gain more than 1ms or the gain will be unnoticeable.  But then, negligible gain in performance is an objective thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you are calling `remote` twice (in some cases) needlessly. 
Consider using this:

```
#include <algorithm>

z = std::max(z, remote(x, y));
```

This will also shorten and clarify the code.

---

Also, it's possible the divisions are slow. Try (after profiling!) replacing

```
x > a / 2 || y > a / 2
```

by

```
(x << 1) > a || (y << 1) > a
```

**Note** @Donnie & others claims in the comments that compilers will do the latter optimization, and they are probably correct.

Comment: The bitshift instead of / 2 (or other powers of 2) is an optimization that most compilers will do in place.

Comment: @Donnie That sounds very logical. I am really not familiar with that many compilers. I guess you're right. I tried to be cautious ("possible", "profile", etc.)

Comment: you mean like:  if ((x << 1) > a || (y << 1) > a) {
   z = min(z, remote(x, y));
   }

Comment: @23ElCaliente Yes, that is the combination of the two suggestions.

Comment: but it is giving me an error on the "max" what header should I put?

Comment: @Donnie Thanks, incorporated your comment.

Comment: it's ok I figured it out :D thanks a lot for the quick reply

Comment: Do not replace division by a constant with bit shifts. Every compiler does this now.

Comment: Thanks, @GManNickG - placed already a comment that the compiler already probably does this, following previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to show you the timings on my machine:

Version 1:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    cin >> x >> y;
   if (x > a / 2 || y > a / 2) {
        if (z > remote(x, y)) {
            z = remote(x, y);
        }               
    }
}
```

Version 2:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    cin >> x >> y;
/*    if (x > a / 2 || y > a / 2) {
        if (z > remote(x, y)) {
            z = remote(x, y);
        }               
    }
 */
}
```

For n=10^5, compiled with -O3 both yield  60ms. Compiled without optimization: both 60ms.

First step for optimizing is to **know** where your program spends time. Reading/parsing the data is the bottle neck.

You could speed up it a little bit by adding as first line to your main:

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

On my machine I'm down to 20ms.

Answer (score 0):

1) Assign a temporary value to the `remote` function:

```
if (x > a / 2 || y > a / 2)
{
    const int r = remote(x,y);
    if (z > r)
    {
        z = r;
    }
}
```

2) Replace the call to `remote` with the contents of `remote`, removing the overhead of a function call:

```
if (x > a / 2 || y > a / 2)
{
    const int r = abs(x) + abs(y);
    if (z > r)
    {
        z = r;
    }
}
```

3) Replace `a / 2` with a constant temporary variable:

```
const int midpoint = a >> 1;
if (x > midpoint || y > midpoint)
```

4) Change compiler optimization level to high - for speed.

5) The bottleneck is now in the input statement.  Any gain by optimizing the remainder of the loop is wasted by the Input time.  There is no more Return On Investment for further changes.